# R method for retrieving Polygon from GeoPackage that contains point

Tags: r, geopackage, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon feature class and a point location and need to retrieve the polygon in which the point occurs. The feature class is in a GeoPackage and I am limited to using R.

I can use any publicly available R packages, but I don't have access to GDAL, OGR etc.

Does anyone have a code example that I can leverage?

Comment: Can I get an explanation how a question how to perform a GIS operation is off topic for A GIS forum please!?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geopackage+r may provide you with some ideas for writing code for R to work with geopackages.  Likewise https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-in-polygon+r may provide you with some ideas for writing code for R to work with points in polygons.  GIS SE is a focused Q&A site which is quite different to a discussion forum, and avoids becoming a code request site by insisting that questions about writing code start with a code attempt.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean with the usage of public R packages like sp, sf or rgeos (but without GDAL). R packages like [sf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) which could be used to [solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925085/3338646) are public but depending on GDAL, PROJ and GEOS.  Is the package [rgeos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) available?